# Is there a way to get the spout msgId from within a bolt?

Tags: apache-storm

There is msgId inside Spout, It is used for ack and fail, The question is can I get this msgId from within the bolts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need the message id. If you're using storm-kafka, you can use the following scheme to get the partition and offset emitted as part of the tuple https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/external/storm-kafka/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/kafka/StringMessageAndMetadataScheme.java. You can set it as part of your SpoutConfig.

If you're using storm-kafka-client, it emits this information by default https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/external/storm-kafka-client/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/kafka/spout/DefaultRecordTranslator.java

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only get msgid of tuples this bolt handles.

If you want to get source msgid the spout emitted, you have to emit the id together with the message.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem that I'm using an out-of- the-box KafkaSpout which will not allow me to change how it emits the tasks.

Comment: What kind of information from the id do you need, and why?

Comment: The msgId inside KafkaSpout methods (ack and fail) is an object KafkaMessageId, which include the partition and the offset of the consumed kafka task. I want to be able to get those two parameters from within a bolt.